# Developing an Advance search for my lists, which approach I can follow

Tags: 2013, development, search

I am working on the following 3 lists inside my SharePoint enterprise server 2013 on-premise :-

1. List Dept.
2. List Area.
3. List Asset. This list have the following main fields:-

   - Title
   - Description
   - Owner
   - Lookup column to the Dept
   - Lookup column to the Area

Now I am trying to build an advance search for the Assets list as follow:-

[image]

Now I already try the metadata navigation for my list, but it has some limitation that I cannot search based on title/description, also the fields will appear on the left side of the screen not at the top (although this is a minor issue). Now for the “Keywords” it will be just like to the built-in search box for the list, but not sure how i can move it inside the advacne search screen.

So can anyone advice on how I can build an advance search for my lists?
Thanks

Comment: do you solved your issue,  may be it help to you https://www.google.com.sa/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=advance%20search%20for%20lists%20in%20sharepoint%202013&oq=advance%20search%20for%20%20lists%20in%20sharepoint%202013&aqs=chrome..69i57.9645j0j7

Comment: @adilahmed no not really ,, still not sure from where i should start if my appraoch require pure development? and what are the built-in capabilities inside sharepoint to achieve this?